# How to get code coverage of Rest Assured testcases for my rest endpoints developed in Spring boot?

Tags: java, rest, integration-testing, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate jacoco code coverage report for my restassured testcases pointing to the rest end points. I am using springboot application.
My controller class looks like :

```
@RestController
public class ChallengeController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChallengeController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ChallengeService challengeService;


    public ChallengeController(ChallengeService challengeService) {
        this.challengeService = challengeService;
    }

    


    @GetMapping(path = "/hello",
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/hello/greeting/{name}",
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return challengeService.greeting(name);
    }

}
```

My service class looks like

```
@Service
@Component
public class ChallengeService {

    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChallengeService.class);



    public ChallengeService() {

    }


    public String greeting(String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
}
```

My POM looks like

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/ResilienceTests.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/CucumberTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/DummyChallengeTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <!-- excluding everything except controller class -->
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/common/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/config/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/domain/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/exception/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/mapper/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/service/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/simulator/Main.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                            <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                            <classFilesDIrectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</classFilesDIrectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- merging jacoco reports-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>merge-results</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>merge</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-merge-report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*CucumberTest.java</include>
                                <include>**/*DummyChallengeTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <!-- When running as a Maven plugin, the JaCoCo agent configuration is prepared by invoking the prepare-agent
                            or prepare-agent-integration goals, before the actual tests are run. This sets a property named argLine which
                            points to the JaCoCo agent, later passed as a JVM argument to the test runner -->

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My test class looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class DummyChallengeTest extends AbstractSteps {



    @Test
    public void testHelloEndpoint() {        
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8082";
        RestAssured.basePath ="/hello";
        Response res = given()
                .when().get()
                .then().log().all()
                .extract().response();
        Assert.assertEquals("hello", res.getBody().asString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGreetingEndpoint() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        //getServiceUrl() returning me the application base url
        String requestUrl = getServiceUrl() + "/hello/greeting/{name}";
                given()
                .pathParam("name", uuid)
                .when().get(requestUrl)
                .then().log().all()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("hello " + uuid)).log().all().extract();
    }
}
```

Inside target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco-sessions.html I can locate my controller and service java files.

I am getting partial coverage on my controller file only these line

```
   @Autowired
    private ChallengeService challengeService;


    public ChallengeController(ChallengeService challengeService) {
        this.challengeService = challengeService;
    }
```

However I am not getting any coverage on the end points, specifically on these lines

```
@GetMapping(path = "/hello",
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/hello/greeting/{name}",
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return challengeService.greeting(name);
    }
```

Note : 1. My restassured testcases runs fine and all are passing.
2. When I am using Quarkus application, and Quarkus Test, then this same jacoco implementation giving me full coverage for end points.
3. I am getting full coverage for my Unit testcases.

When I am using Quarkus application, and Quarkus Test, then this same jacoco implementation giving me full coverage for end points.

I have seen some people are saying to run your application and test from same jvm. I am not sure how to do this correctly. Also if this solution is possible to implement in jenkins pipeline.

I have not tried Arquillian yet.

Comment: Do you have any unit tests running?

Comment: Yes. My unit test coverage is perfectly generated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved it or not. Sorry for not posting earlier.

It seems like you some misconfigurations in the plugin settings.

The steps should be:

1. Prepare agent for unit tests
2. Report the unit tests coverage in the `test` phase
3. Prepare agent for integration tests in the `pre-integration-test` phase
4. Report the integration tests coverage in the `post-integration-test` phase
5. Merge the two reports in the `post-integration-test` phase
6. Report the merged report from step no. 5 in the `post-integration-test` phase
7. Run a coverage check against the reported merged report from step 6 in the `verify` phase

So, all in all, it should look something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Prepare the agent for the Unit Tests -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Generate the report for the Unit Tests -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Prepare the agent for the Integration Tests -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Generate the report for the Integration Test -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- excluding everything except controller class -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/common/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/config/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/domain/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/exception/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/mapper/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/service/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/simulator/Main.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                <classFilesDIrectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</classFilesDIrectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        
        <!-- Merge Unit Tests and Integration Tests reports -->
        <execution>
            <id>merge-unit-and-integration</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.exec</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/merged.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Report the merged report -->
        <execution>
            <id>report-merged-report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/merged.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-merged</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Check the coverage -->
        <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <!-- Make sure you exclude your tests from coverage -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*Test</exclude>
                            <exclude>*IT</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <!-- This will probably fail your build :) -->
                                <minimum>100</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/merged.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```